# How can I check the expiry details for many SSL certificates deployed on Windows 2008/2012 servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

We have 300+ Windows servers for .NET hosting purposes and a lot of SSL certificates imported on these servers. Can we pull the certificate expiry details for all servers from a single Windows/Linux server using PowerShell or Python?

Answer (score 5):

`Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My` will list all of the machine certificates installed.

to do the same to a remote server, use remoting:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My}`

or all of your servers:

```
$certs = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'ou=servers,dc=something,dc=com' -filter *
    | % { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.name -ScriptBlock
        { Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\my }
    }'
```

Comment: If you only interested in expired ones, or ones that will expire say within 30 days use: `Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My  | Where NotAfter -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(30)`

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do this would be with a simple curl of the website using the following flags:

```
curl -ILv https://yourdomainhere.com
```

in the output, you'll find an expire string "expire date" that looks something like this:

```
*    expire date: 2016-05-19 20:59:53 GMT
```

use pycurl to get this to work, ingest it as a string, then pull out the relevant data. OR, you could use the following python script for *nix boxes to test from (it's a bit rough and could use tweaking to accept all hosts/domains to check):

```
import os
os.system("echo|openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -dates > ~/testfile.txt")
```

Comment: This would require a list of URIs to check, also what about certificates that are not bound to web sites? It is much more robust to enumerate the certificates on each server.

Comment: for something like that, you're going to need to likely use a config management system/devops tool such as puppet/chef/salt/ansible to execute an openssl command as ssl not bound to a site would require reading the ssl file manually. Alternatively, you could use the above config management system/devops/system management tools to read the ssl files and parse them on a local machine that has openssl or an ssl-checker installed.

Comment: No you don't. All you need is the few line of PowerShell mentioned in longneck's answer. Remember this is for Windows servers.